# How to get US states on a Google visualization choropleth

Tags: google-visualization, choropleth

I am trying to make a choropleth over drug death rates in the US states. 
However, I cannot get the state boarders to appear, only Alaska and Hawaii, and I cannot seem to figure out why. 
Still, a little new at this, so hope someone can help!

This is my code:

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {'packages':["geochart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);
  function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Region',   'Age-adjusted mortality rate per 100,000'],
      ['Alaska', 16.8], 
      ['Alabama', -8], 
      ['Arizona', 6], 
      ['Arkansas', -24],
      ['California', 12],
      ['Colorado', -3], 
      ['Connecticut', 3],
      ['Delaware', 28], 
      ['Florida', 15],
      ['Georgia', 4], 
      ['Hawaii', 35], 
      ['Idaho', 12],
      ['Illinois', -12], 
      ['Indiana', 6],
      ['Iowa', -3], 
      ['Kansas', 12],
      ['Kentucky', 26], 
      ['Louisiana', 3], 
      ['Maine', 15],
      ['Maryland', 9], 
      ['Massachusetts', 0], 
      ['Michigan', 13], 
      ['Minnesota', 5],
      ['Mississippi', 10], 
      ['Missouri', 12], 
      ['Montana', -1],
      ['Nebraska', -29], 
      ['Nevada', 6], 
      ['New Hampshire', 32], 
      ['New Jersey', null],
      ['New Mexico', 33], 
      ['New York', -14], 
      ['North Carolina', 12], 
      ['North Dakota', 18],
      ['Ohio', -20], 
      ['Oklahoma', -13], 
      ['Oregon', 35],
      ['Pennsylvania  ', 32], 
      ['Rhode Island', -25], 
      ['South Carolina', -22],
      ['South Dakota', 14], 
      ['Tennessee', 8], 
      ['Texas', -1],
      ['Utah', -21], 
      ['Vermont', -2], 
      ['Virginia', -16],
      ['Washington', 0], 
      ['West Virginia', 15],
      ['Wisconsin', -5], 
      ['Wyoming', 8]
    ]);

    var options = {
      region: 'US', 
      colorAxis: {colors: ['#00853f', 'black', '#e31b23']},
      backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
      datalessRegionColor: '#f8bbd0',
      defaultColor: '#f5f5f5'

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  };
</script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for: `resolution: 'provinces'`

```js
  google.load("visualization", "1", {'packages':["geochart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);
  function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Region',   'Age-adjusted mortality rate per 100,000'],
      ['Alaska', 16.8], 
      ['Alabama', -8], 
      ['Arizona', 6], 
      ['Arkansas', -24],
      ['California', 12],
      ['Colorado', -3], 
      ['Connecticut', 3],
      ['Delaware', 28], 
      ['Florida', 15],
      ['Georgia', 4], 
      ['Hawaii', 35], 
      ['Idaho', 12],
      ['Illinois', -12], 
      ['Indiana', 6],
      ['Iowa', -3], 
      ['Kansas', 12],
      ['Kentucky', 26], 
      ['Louisiana', 3], 
      ['Maine', 15],
      ['Maryland', 9], 
      ['Massachusetts', 0], 
      ['Michigan', 13], 
      ['Minnesota', 5],
      ['Mississippi', 10], 
      ['Missouri', 12], 
      ['Montana', -1],
      ['Nebraska', -29], 
      ['Nevada', 6], 
      ['New Hampshire', 32], 
      ['New Jersey', null],
      ['New Mexico', 33], 
      ['New York', -14], 
      ['North Carolina', 12], 
      ['North Dakota', 18],
      ['Ohio', -20], 
      ['Oklahoma', -13], 
      ['Oregon', 35],
      ['Pennsylvania  ', 32], 
      ['Rhode Island', -25], 
      ['South Carolina', -22],
      ['South Dakota', 14], 
      ['Tennessee', 8], 
      ['Texas', -1],
      ['Utah', -21], 
      ['Vermont', -2], 
      ['Virginia', -16],
      ['Washington', 0], 
      ['West Virginia', 15],
      ['Wisconsin', -5], 
      ['Wyoming', 8]
    ]);

    var options = {
      region: 'US', 
      colorAxis: {colors: ['#00853f', 'black', '#e31b23']},
      backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
      datalessRegionColor: '#f8bbd0',
      defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
      resolution: 'provinces'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="geochart-colors" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```